# how to convert a python dict object to a java equivalent object?

Tags: java, python, hashmap, dictionary

I need to convert a python code into an equivalent java code. Python makes life very easy for the developers by providing lots of shortcut functionalities. But now I need to migrate the same to Java. I was wondering what will the equivalent of dict objects in java? I have tried using HashMap but life is hell. For starters consider this,

```
#  Nodes is a dictionary -> Key : (Name, Strength)
for node, (name, strength) in nodes.items():
    nodes[node] = (name, new_strength)
```

So how to go about converting this into Java?
For starters I used HashMap object so,

```
Map<Integer, List> nodesMap = new HashMap<Integer,List>();
/* For iterating over the map */
Iterator updateNodeStrengthIterator = nodesMap.entrySet().iterator(); 
while(updateNodeStrengthIterator.hasNext()){ }
```

My problem is in getting the List part which contains Name & Strength & then updating the Strength part. Is there any feasible way to do this? Should I consider some different data structure? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably easiest to just create a class for the (Name, Strength) tuple:

```
class NameStrength {
    public String name;
    public String strength;
}
```

Add getters, setters and a constructor if appropriate.

Then you can use the new class in your map:

```
Map<Integer, NameStrength> nodesMap = new HashMap<Integer, NameStrength>();
```

In Java 5 and up, you can iterate like this:

```
for (NameStrength nameStrength : nodesMap.values()) {}
```

or like this:

```
for (Entry<Integer, NameStrength> entry : nodesMap.entrySet()) {}
```

Comment: thanks. thats very helpful. i was just hoping to get more succint approach.

Comment: Ah well, unfortunately, succinctness isn't one of Java's strengths...

Answer (score 3):

well there's always [jython](http://www.jython.org/).
here's a little bit from [this article](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/03/27/jython.html) that offers a good side by side view of python/java

> The Jython analogues to Java's
>   collection classes are much more
>   tightly integrated into the core
>   language, allowing for more concise
>   descriptions and useful functionality.
>   For example, notice the difference
>   between the Java code:
>
> ```
> map = new HashMap();
> map.put("one",new Integer(1));
> map.put("two",new Integer(2));
> map.put("three",new Integer(3));
>
> System.out.println(map.get("one"));
>
> list = new LinkedList();
> list.add(new Integer(1));
> list.add(new Integer(2));
> list.add(new Integer(3));
> ```
>
> and the Jython code:
>
> ```
> map = {"one":1,"two":2,"three":3}
> print map ["one"]
> list = [1, 2, 3]
> ```

---

edit: what's wrong with just using put() to replace the values?

```
map.put(key,new_value);
```

here's a small example program:

```
static public void main(String[] args){
    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
     //name, age
    map.put("billy", 21);
    map.put("bobby", 19);
    year(map);
    for(String i: map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(i+ " " + map.get(i).toString());
    }
}
// a year has passed
static void year(HashMap<String,Integer> m){
    for(String k: m.keySet()){
        m.put(k, m.get(k)+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. but I cannot use Jython due to some restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have the equivalent of a tuple built-in.  You would have to create a class that encapsulated the two together to mimic it.